# Python: Plotting multiple data sets; pre-defining all colors and markers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a Pandas Dataframe in which each column represents a different data set, and I'd like to plot them all together.  I can simply call `plt.plot(df)` and it does it perfectly well.  I have two questions:

1. How can I change the default colors of the plots?  That is, how can I force a different colormap?
2. Is there any way of giving all plot symbols in one go, so to speak?

I know I can define the plot style for each column separately, such as:

```
plt.plot(df['col1'],'ro-',df['col2'],'b*--',df['col3'],'go-.')
```

But I was hoping for something more concise, along the lines of:

```
plt.plot(df,colors=colors, styles=styles, markers=markers)
```

where the variables `colors`, `styles` and `markers` have been previously defined.  Or maybe something along the lines of:

```
plt.colors = <something that defines colors>
plt.styles = ...
plt.markers = ...
plt.plot(df)
```

I know that there is no `plt.styles`, but is there something which would have the same effect: that is, predefine all possible line styles to be used in a multiline plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Styling with cycler](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html) tutorial in the documentation.

```
from cycler import cycler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mycycler = (cycler(color=['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']) +
            cycler(linestyle=['-', '--', ':', '-.']) + 
            cycler(marker=['s', 'o', 'd', '^']))
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=mycycler)


plt.plot(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4)))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this is exactly what I was looking for!  I have marked your answer as accepted.